# Interpretation for multivariable functions graphing

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

First of all, I'm new to multivariable calculus... in a multivariable function, by assuming that its domain is going to be $R^{2}$  and its image is going to be all real numbers, the graph of that function is defined as a  subset of $R^{3}$ in which the $x$ and $y$ axis are going to receive the inputs, and the output is going to be in $z$ $(x,y,f(x,y))$ ? Is that correct? Will its graph, in this example, be some kind of surface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If such a $f(x,y)$ is defined for all real pairs $(x,y)$, for each such pair corresponds a single real value, which could be taken as the $z$ coordinate of a point. This interpretation leads to a surface, as you suppose.

Using Wolfram Alpha, for instance, you can get the plots of the following functions. Guessing the surfaces before looking them up would be an interesting exercise.

$f(x,y)=x$

$f(x,y)=y$

$f(x,y)=x+y$

$f(x,y)=x-y$

After you understand these graphs, you may look into surfaces [such as this one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-(xy)%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E2)) which are still quite simply expressed, but fairly more interesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Do you have any multivariable calculus book to recommend?

Comment: @BrunoReis I particularly like Calculus: Early Transcendentals by James Stewart. However, the book is expensive and this is a popular enough subject so that finding good lectures (mostly from universities that recorded their classes) and free material on the Internet is also easy. Additionally, by following an online course you will have a well-defined roadmap for your learning.

Comment: I'll follow sal khan, fromm khan academy... ty anyway my friend